# First-order linear differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $x$ be a function of  $C^1(I,R)$ where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ , such that  $$x'(t)\leq a(t) x(t)+b(t),$$ where $a$ and $b$ are continuous functions on  $I$ in $R$ then 
>   $$ x(t)\leq x(t_0) \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)ds\right)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\exp\left(\int_{s}^t a(\sigma)d\sigma\right)b(s)ds$$

How to prove this proposition please ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like a Grönwall-type inequality, so I would assume that a minor adjustment to the proof of Grönwall's inequality would do.

Comment: @Sisyphus how i must start please,

Comment: @Sisyphus from $x'(t)\leq a(t)x(t)+b(t)$ by integration over $[t_0,t]$ i obtain that $x(t)\leq x_0+\int_{t_0}^t a(s) x(s) ds+\int_{t_0}^t b(s) ds$ but i don't think that it can help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I, too, first guessed this would be a problem suggesting the application of [Grownall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality), but it seems an even more elementary solution avails itself:

Given that

$x'(t) \le a(t) x(t) + b(t), \tag 1$

we have the equivalent form

$x'(t) - a(t) x(t) \le b(t); \tag 2$

and since

$\displaystyle \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right )  > 0 \tag 3$

we further have

$\displaystyle \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right )(x'(t) - a(t) x(t)) \le  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(t); \tag 4$

we observe that

$\displaystyle \left ( \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(t) \right )' = \displaystyle -a(t) \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(t) + \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x'(t)$
$= \displaystyle \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right )(x'(t) - a(t)x(t)); \tag 5$

thus (4) becomes

$\displaystyle \left ( \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(t) \right )' \le  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(t); \tag 6$

we integrate (6) 'twixt $t_0$ and $t$:

$\displaystyle  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(t)  - x(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^t \left ( \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(s) \right )'\; ds$
$\le \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds, \tag 7$

whence

$\displaystyle  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) x(t) \le x(t_0) + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds, \tag 8$

which we multiply through by

$\displaystyle  \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) > 0 \tag 9$

to obtain

$x(t) \le$
$\displaystyle x(t_0) \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right )$
$+ \exp \left (\displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds; \tag{10}$

finally,

$\displaystyle \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds$
$= \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds, \tag{11}$

and since

$\displaystyle  \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) \exp \left (-\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds$
$= \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma -\int_{t_0}^s a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds$
$= \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (\int_s^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds, \tag{12}$

(10) becomes

$x(t) \le \displaystyle x(t_0) \exp \left (\int_{t_0}^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) + \int_{t_0}^t  \exp \left (\int_s^t a(\sigma)\; d\sigma \right ) b(s) \; ds, \tag{14}$

which, since $s$ and $\sigma$ are in fact merely so-called "dummy" variables of integration, is indeed the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the differential equation

$x′(t)+d(t)= a(t)x(t)+b(t)$

for some $d\geq 0$. When you get the explicit solution, just recall the sign $d$ had.